# set url id, fetch it, then use in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Good day all,

I am building a messaging system that functions similar to that of Facebook. 
I will just post the code that's mostly important and where I am in need of help mostly.

The following php code fetches all of the conversations from a database and this is working well.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_convo)){

  $memberid = $row['ID'];
  $convoid = $row['conversation_id'];

echo"
<button onclick='getconvo($convoid)'>open</button>
";
}
```

Notice that the above while loop outputs a button that holds the $convoid VALUE for each conversation. This is the unique ID value for each conversation generated from database.

The following javascript code proved that the above code works because it alerts the conversation ID VALUE for each button clicked. 
Actually, picture that each button is a conversation with unique $convoid VALUE.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getconvo(id){ 
var convoid = id;
alert(convoid);
}
</script>
```

Given the above information, here is what I want to accomplish in simple steps in the right order:

- the id VALUE for each button click is sent to the URL bar
- the id VALUE is gotten from the URL bar and is used to search a mysql database to obtain results based on the id VALUE.
- that obtained results are loaded into a div on the same page where the button was clicked.
- that i can use the same id VALUE fetched from the URL to do another task involving mysql database search.

Note that all of these should be accomplished without a page reload/refresh...just like Facebook, when switching from on conversation to the next.

How do I go about doing these?

Comment: Without reloading the page means AJAX, and if you want to manipulate the URL in the address bar as well, look into the HTML5 History API.

Comment: Okay. So, I can use AJAX to have an ID variable sent to a page and this page uses that ID to fetch information from a database (like history messages) Yes? And if so, I can use that same ID value to post new replies to that user (even though the page is generated through AJAX and not directly). Yes?

Comment: Yes, and yes. (The browser does not care how a page was generated, it just cares about what is currently there.)

Comment: Okay, but, I used this code and it seemed to work BUT... I am unable to use the ID VALUE  that was sent to the php file (through the java code you are seeing) to do another task on that php file that was loaded.

Comment: I am unable to use the ID VALUE  that was sent to the php file to do another task on that php file that was loaded <script type='text/javascript'>
function getconvo(id){ 
var convoid = id;
$('.convo').load('fetch_convo.php', {id : convoid}, function () {});}
</script> This code gets the ID value from the button clicked and passes it to php file. which loads with updated result.  On that loaded page, I am trying to use that SAME id value to do a post of a message to that user. But I am unable to use the id on that page to execute the post/reply query. Why? and what do I do?

Comment: If you make a new request, you of course need to pass the parameters again. There is no connection between to requests in HTTP.

Comment: I used the javascript above to pass the id variable to the php file, and on the same time, load that php file with updated result based on id value. Can I now use the passed id value on the loaded page to execute another script from scratch on that same loaded page where the scrip is written? How do I go about doing that? (Remember, I did not define the id on that loaded page. I instead passed it through the java code since everybody button clicked has it's own id value)

Comment: Just add a second `$.load()` in your function …?

Comment: Okay, but what am I loading with that second load now?

Comment: Did you not want to load a second PHP script? Or did you mean you want to do something with the value in JavaScript on the client side?

Comment: So, on the loaded page (fetch.convo.php) the history messages are loaded based on the id value passed with the java code. But on that same fetch.php page (the page that is being loaded with the java code together with the id value), there is a reply form. When I type text, i click a reply button. On that button click, it has to use the SAME id value that was loaded using the java code to send the message to the right person. So that is what i am trying to achieve.. That part of the script to send message is only executed when i decided to reply to a message.

Comment: So store the id from the button into a JS variable so that you have access to it later … or something like that. If your reply form uses for example a hidden input field to submit the id, then you can also set it as the value of that field at the time you click your first button.

Comment: alright...well I will try that or something similar and get back to you. .But If i could achieve something like Facebook..that be good.. if you pay attention to Facebook, on switching conversations, every time you click a new person's name, the id is loaded into the url, then the id is gotten from the url to load the cono into a div. I will keep you updated

Comment: UPDATING... so, your suggestion working so far. I hope that this solution work consistently for the rest of my project. I am actually new to this php/javascript business. If you know of any good resource that I can use to teach me like a pro, I would gladly like to have access to it.